# Is Wonder Woman Immortal?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

In the ***Wonder Woman*** movie she was born before WWI and in the BvS she was fighting doomsday. It doesn't look like she is aged a little bit.

Is she immortal or having a slow aging rate?

Whether she will get old?

Answer (score 1):

She starts as a child and becomes an adult.  So she can grow up but not clear if she can age.

Also she killed a god so she can probably die.